# SWIFT: 'SecPolicy' does not have a member named 'takeRetainedValue'

Tags: ios, swift

My Project had worked perfectly with SwiftHTTP in XCode 7 beta 3, before I've updated XCode 7 to beta 5.

Now I get the error: 'SecPolicy' does not have a member named 'takeRetainedValue'.

```
var policy: SecPolicyRef
    if self.validatedDN {
        policy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(1, domain).takeRetainedValue()
    } else {
        policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509().takeRetainedValue()
    }
```

Is there any oppotunity to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 9, the Security framework returns values that are automatically memory managed, as opposed to being `Unmanaged` references. As such, you no longer need to call `takeRetainedValue()` (indeed, you can't, since they're no longer returning `Unmanaged` values), so just delete those calls and the system will release them automatically when needed.

For more info on unmanaged Core Foundation references, see [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_51) in the *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* guide.