# SecAccessControl has no member takeRetainedValue

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, touch-id

I'm followig this link https://www.cigital.com/blog/integrating-touch-id-into-ios-applications/

```
let sacRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
        kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
        .UserPresence,
        &error);

let data: NSData = "sup3r_s3cur3_k3y".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!;

    var attributes: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(
        objects: [  kSecClassGenericPassword,
                    service,
                    data,
                    kCFBooleanTrue,
                    sacRef.takeRetainedValue()
        ],
        forKeys: [  kSecClass,
                    kSecAttrService,
                    kSecValueData,
                    kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI,
                    kSecAttrAccessControl]);

var status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionaryRef, nil);
```

on the line `sacRef.takeRetainedValue()`I get `Value of type 'SecAccessControl' has no member 'takeRetainedValue'`

How should I save TouchID protected data into the Keychain?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `sacRef.takeRetainedValue()` by `sacRef`? – Probably the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023477/swift-secpolicy-does-not-have-a-member-named-takeretainedvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove it. Most frameworks no longer need it since Swift 2.3+.

I just tried to upgrade one of my Swift 2.0 app to Swift 2.3. It reported the same issue. I simply removed it. It compiled and worked like a charm.